# How to count the no. of loans amount above $100,000 as per the below data

Tags: excel-formula

How to count the no. of loans amount above $100,000?

[image]

tried using this

```
= COUNT(D8:D25,IF(D8>=100000,1,0))
```

But valus seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
= COUNTIF(D8:D25,">=100000")
```